# Moped dies when trying to give gas after filling up gas tank

Tags: maintenance, gasoline, moped

My moped has been running just fine lately but after I put gas in it immediately started choking off when I give it gas. The tank was pretty close to empty when I topped it off. Is that the reason that all of a sudden the moped doesn't run properly?

Answer (score 1):

- **Scenario 1**

  Your carburettor might have been flooded, the fuel pump(vending machine) has a certain
  pressure with which it pours in fuel to your tank, your moped being
  small I am guessing not more that 4 litres of fuel capacity will be a
  small tank and when you are pretty close to empty or empty the
  pressure of the fuel coming in can flood your carburettor which will
  choke for a mile or two after that it should resume working properly.

  It is basically like pulling up the choke on your moped , it floods the carb. 
  To  avoid such situations always remember to shut off the fuel valve before filling up.
- **Scenario 2**

  You might have overfilled the tank and sealed it sort of
  air tight,       sometimes(common on olden motorcycles & Mopeds)when
  you fill up the tank too  much and close the lid without any sort of
  gap in the tank for air , it creates a partial vacuum and the fuel
  will not be able to freely flow to the carb thus casing it to choke

  solution is to open the tank and reseal it slowly allowing some air to get in or remove some fuel.
- **Scenario 3**

  There is a high chance that you might have put it adulterated or bad fuel in your moped, this will definitely clog the engine part and will cause issues to an otherwise smooth engine.

Udate:

As your friend suggested, the fuel filter could also be an issue do check it.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions! I was able to get it up to around 10mph by very lightly giving it gas but once I gave it to much it would choke off again. I went around the block a couple of times and nothing improved at all. I also took some gas out and ran it with the cap off to troubleshoot scenario 2. its the gas station I normally fill up at so that could be it. One of the guys I work with suggested that since i let the gas get so low some of the sediment that floats on the top usually was pushed through when i filled up. He suggested a new fuel filter to see if that works

Comment: Ive had problems like this before on this moped and just had a new carbureter put in late August so not to sure what else it could be this time. We had a bunch of rain the day before this all happened but was using it for half a day before I went to the gas station to fill up

Comment: @MichaelBall So have you tried all of the above solutions?